# VSTO Outlook Plugin - Get and set proposed new time for meeting programatically

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am working on VSTO based outlook plugin, where I am looking for an option to programmatically send a meeting response as TentativelyAccept/Decline along with proposing new time. I see AppointmentItem.Respond method - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.respond
however, that doesn't have any option to set propose new time.

Similarly, when attendee send new time proposal manually I want to get that time from my outlook plugin.

Also, if organizer opens up that meeting, I want to read like attendee XX has tentatively accepted meeting and proposed new time. In outlook meeting window we can clearly see that however, not getting any option to read programmatically from plugin.

Is there any property/MAPI through that I can get/set this information?

Thanks,